Extract week of date in power query
I use the M query function to extract the week # from a column, quite straightforward i would say. However the result isn't...
I use the following formula:
 Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Week #", each Date.WeekOfYear([Datum]))
Where [datum] is a column header. this column shows e.g.:

The results should be week # 1. However Power query shows week 2.
Is anyone seeing the issue? Thanks a lot!

In your example the 01-01-2023 falls on a sunday. The Date.WeekOfYear() labels the week, which contains the 01.01., as week 1. In Europe another standard (ISO 8601) is widely used.
To implement the Week # in ISO 8601 format you could consider this blog post.
Another option is to calculate the week number as an calculated column in DAX as Week # = WEEKNUM('Table'[Datum], 21) (Ref). The second argument of the function specifies the week's start day and usage of ISO 8601 format.
